# Remote database, local theme files

Tags: theme, database, mysql

I have a team for which we would all like to be editing the same MySQL database for Magento.  We have one installed on a test site on a server we all have access to.

However, I would like to be theming the site on my local computer since SFTP and SSH mounting have been far too slow for me for editing/switching between files.

I have figured out how to connect my local installation to the remote database, however, I don't know how to ***make Magento look for the theme files on each of our developer's local machines***, rather than on the server.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to configure it this way, what you can do is configure a magento installation on every developer machine and use the remote database like you did for the server installation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I do want to have a separate Magento installation on each machine, just all of them referencing the same database...?

Comment: @blisstdev, Database is one thing, there is also a web server (apache, nginx) which serves Magento itself and this has to be placed on each local environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

1. Install a httpd (apache/nginx) on your local machine, which runs magento
2. Install magento
3. Configure magento to use the remote database*
4. edit the local theme files

`*` You want to make sure only you can access this database, either by using a VPN or by using MySQL via SSL/TLS.